# No yum repos on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.2 (Tikanga)

Tags: rhel, yum

I have a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.2 (Tikanga) system and there is only one repository named rhel-debuginfo.repo and it doesn't seem to work either.

Could you point me out some default yum repositories needed for maintaining a development system (which includes svn, mvn, httpd, tomcat etc.)

Comment: I think that's available to subscribed user only , you may need to pay for it

Comment: @warl0ck thanks. Looking for other options.

Comment: Use centos instead , it's based on RHEL , provide free updates

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Red Hat Entreprise Linux 5, you need to set up the system to connect to RHN.  Read [Red Hat's Documentation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/entitlements.html#overview-of-entitlements) on the subject.  You can get a free 30-day test license if you are interested in testing it out.

The other solution is to reinstall the host with [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/), [Scientific Linux](http://www.scientificlinux.org/), or one of the [many other RHEL-derivitives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_derivatives).

(**EDIT**: linked distro names)